# Authors divided alphabetically

Tags: author

I'd like to create a page on my site listing all of the site's contributors with info like their bio, URL, etc..

I found [this code](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-an-author-list-with-avatars-in-wordpress-contributors-page/) which is perfectly suited for my needs. However, what I'd like to do is have this code break contributors up alphabetically by last name (or by username if a full name is unavailable) with a header and anchor tag for each letter. Ie.:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

A

Bill Abrams
Tom Anderson

B

John Biskup
Steve Botwin

C

etc.
```

Any thoughts on how to modify the linked code above to achieve that?

Comment: If you want solid answers, I'd recommend copying the relevant code into your question. This would save those willing to answer the time spent hunting it down.

Comment: This questions requires work on your part, that example you linked is bad code, use `WP_User_Query` then parse the results to create alphabetical lists with something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812097/listing-array-values-alphabetically-with-letter-heading

Comment: @Wyck, you're my hero. Here's what I ended up with:
https://gist.github.com/74ea28d039b5165ae6f3

Comment: You should add that as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up with. Totally does the trick, minus the sorting by last name. Would love to hear any additional thoughts on that.

```
$display_admins = false;
$order_by = 'display_name'; // 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', or 'post_count'
$role = ''; // 'subscriber', 'contributor', 'editor', 'author' - leave blank for 'all'
$avatar_size = 32;
$hide_empty = true; // hides authors with zero posts
$last = '';

if(!empty($display_admins)) {
    $blogusers = get_users('orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
} else {
    $admins = get_users('role=administrator');
    $exclude = array();
    foreach($admins as $ad) {
        $exclude[] = $ad->ID;
    }
    $exclude = implode(',', $exclude);
    $blogusers = get_users('exclude='.$exclude.'&orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
}
$authors = array();
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    $user = get_userdata($bloguser->ID);
    if(!empty($hide_empty)) {
        $numposts = count_user_posts($user->ID);
        if($numposts < 1) continue;
    }
    $authors[] = (array) $user;
}

echo '<ul class="contributors">';
foreach($authors as $author) {
    $current = strtolower($author['data']->display_name[0]);
    $display_name = $author['data']->display_name;
    $avatar = get_avatar($author['ID'], $avatar_size);
    $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($author['ID']);

    if ($last != $current) {
        echo '<a class"alphabit" name="' . strtoupper($current) . '">' . strtoupper($current) . '</a>';
            $last = $current;
    }
    echo '<li><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">', $avatar , '</a><a href="', $author_profile_url, '" class="contributor-link">', $display_name, '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Just remember to accept your own answer when the 2 day restriction is lifted. :-)